# Alignment on y-axis doesn't respond flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want a CircleAvatar over an Image so I created a stack, its children are an Image and an Align (CircleAvatar inside).

All seems works but I can't move the CircleAvatar on the y-axis, only on the x-axis and I really need to move it on the y-axis.

Code :

```
body: new Stack(
 children: <Widget>[
   new ListView(
     children: <Widget>[
       new Stack(
         children: <Widget>[
           new Image.asset('assets/images/io.png',
             fit : BoxFit.contain,
           ),
           new Align(
             alignment: Alignment(0,0),
             child: new CircleAvatar(
               minRadius: 50,
               maxRadius: 50,
               child : ClipRRect(
                 borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50),
                 child :  _profPicture == null
                     ? new Image.asset('assets/images/empty_profile.jpg')
                     : _profPicture,
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ],
       ),

         ],
       ),
     ],
   ),
```

If I change the values inside "Alignment" I can move only the avatar from the left to the right, top-bottom doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Align Widget, you should use Positioned Widget

```
  Positioned(
            top: 30,
            right: 30,
            child: new CircleAvatar(.....)
```

Comment: I know but I don't like to move widgets using pixels, I prefer to use movements based on percentage to avoid overflow like Align. Is there a way? On different devices the layout change, I would like to avoid it.

Comment: @MichealRoss: Where you want to align your Avatar?

Comment: I don't know but somewhere over the picture. Currently I decided to put the avatar on the edge of the picture but when I move it there it's cut. Parts outside the picture disappear.

Comment: why you are not alignment propery like alignment: Alignment.topRight

Comment: Because I want to set it exactly where I want

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved by specifying child container height and width that need to be aligned. The problem was I only specified width. So height matched to the parent. So no movement on y axis